# Different results in awk when using different FS syntax

Tags: awk, rhel

I have a sample file which contains the following.

```
logging.20160309.113.txt.log:  0 Rows successfully loaded.
logging.20160309.1180.txt.log:  0 Rows successfully loaded.
logging.20160309.1199.txt.log:  0 Rows successfully loaded.
```

I currently am familiar with 2 ways of implementing a Field Separator syntax in awk. However, I am currently getting different results.

For the longest time I use

"FS=" syntax when my FS is more than one character.

"-f" flag when my FS is just one character.

I would like to understand why the FS= syntax is giving me an unexpected result as seen below. Somehow the 1st record is being left behind.

```
$ head -3 reload_list | awk -F"\.log\:" '{ print $1 }'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\:' treated as plain `:'
logging.20160309.113.txt
logging.20160309.1180.txt
logging.20160309.1199.txt
$ head -3 reload_list |  awk '{ FS="\.log\:" } { print $1 }'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\:' treated as plain `:'
logging.20160309.113.txt.log:
logging.20160309.1180.txt
logging.20160309.1199.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting different results, is that in the case where you set `FS` in the awk program, it is not in a `BEGIN` block. So by the time you've set it, the first record has already been parsed into fields (using the default separator).

**Setting with `-F`**

```
 $ awk -F"\\.log:" '{ print $1 }' b.txt
 logging.20160309.113.txt
 logging.20160309.1180.txt
 logging.20160309.1199.txt
```

**Setting `FS` *after* parsing first record**

```
$ awk '{ FS= "\\.log:"} { print $1 }' b.txt
logging.20160309.113.txt.log:
logging.20160309.1180.txt
logging.20160309.1199.txt
```

**Setting `FS` before parsing any records**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS= "\\.log:"} { print $1 }' b.txt
logging.20160309.113.txt
logging.20160309.1180.txt
logging.20160309.1199.txt
```

I noticed this relevant bit in an awk manual. If perhaps you've seen different behavior previously or with a different implementation, this could explain why:

> According to the POSIX standard, `awk` is supposed to behave as if
>   each record is split into fields at the time that it is read.  In
>   particular, this means that you can change the value of `FS` after a
>   record is read, but before any of the fields are referenced.  The value
>   of the fields (i.e. how they were split) should reflect the old value
>   of `FS`, not the new one.
>
> However, many implementations of `awk` do not do this.  Instead,
>   they defer splitting the fields until a field reference actually
>   happens, using the *current* value of `FS`!  This behavior can be
>   difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Accepting this as the best answer for providing manual references.

Answer (score 0):

`-f` is for running a script from a file. `-F` and `FS` works the same

```
$ awk -F'.log' '{print $1}' logs
logging.20160309.113.txt
logging.20160309.1180.txt
logging.20160309.1199.txt

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=".log"} {print $1}' logs
logging.20160309.113.txt
logging.20160309.1180.txt
logging.20160309.1199.txt
```

Comment: I know it doesn't affect the output but strictly speaking, I guess that it should be `\\.log` in both cases.