# awk -OFS vs OFS gives different output

Tags: awk

I have a sample file:

```sh
~/dev/test[1]⑂master*$ cat test.properties
startTime: 0515
stopTime: 2015
dataFiles: foo
fixVersion: 4.2
retry: 5
kafkaRelay.type: kafkaSink
kafkaRelay.producerId: blah
kafkaRelay.partitioningTag: 49
kafkaRelay.topic: topicname-pre-transform-{0,date,yyyyMMdd}
```

I have a particular awk command I want to run. It gives different output when I use `-F` vs `{BEGIN FS = ...`:

```sh
~/dev/test[4]⑂master*$  awk  'BEGIN{ FS = ": *"; OFS =": " } \
    $1 ~ /(startTime|fixVersion)/ {print $2, $1}; \
    $1 ~ /kafkaRelay.topic/ {$1="kafkaWriter.topic";print; $1="kafkaReader.topic"; print}; \
    $1 ~ /stopTime/ { $2+=100; $2%=2400; printf("%s: %04d\n", $1, $2) }' test.properties
0515: startTime
stopTime: 2115
4.2: fixVersion
kafkaWriter.topic: topicname-pre-transform-{0,date,yyyyMMdd}
kafkaReader.topic: topicname-pre-transform-{0,date,yyyyMMdd}
~/dev/test[5]⑂master*$ awk -F': *' -OFS': ' \
   '$1 ~ /(startTime|fixVersion)/ {print $2, $1}; \
    $1 ~ /kafkaRelay.topic/ {$1="kafkaWriter.topic";print; $1="kafkaReader.topic"; print}; \
    $1 ~ /stopTime/ { $2+=100; $2%=2400; printf("%s: %04d\n", $1, $2) }' test.properties
 startTime: 0515
stopTime: 2015: 0100
 fixVersion: 4.2
kafkaWriter.topic
kafkaReader.topic
```

The first version outputs exactly as I expect. The second version has a bunch of differences and I don't understand how they come about. I also tried 1-4 `\` in front of the `*` in the second version, hoping it was something to do with escaping the `*`, but that had no effect.

Why does this happen? I followed [awk's regexp field splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html), and the [command line field separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Field-Separator.html) doesn't have any special instructions for `-F` vs `FS =`. The [only StackOverflow question I could find fails to use `BEGIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105289/different-results-in-awk-when-using-different-fs-syntax), which isn't my problem.

For reference:

```sh
~/dev/test[6]⑂master*$ awk --version
GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
```

Comment: err, `-OFS`? I'm not aware of that being valid as a comand-line argument, and wouldn't be the slightest bit surprised if it were being treated as `-O` `-FS` (thus turning on optimization -- which is already on-by-default in gawk -- and then overriding the `-F ': *'`, by changing the field separator to just be the character `S`).

Comment: Can you cite any documentation indicating that `-OFS` _should_ work?

Comment: ... yeah I have no idea where that thought came from. That's the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, do you want to post that as an answer, or should I delete this question?

Comment: `-F': *'` is essentially a shortcut for `-v FS=': *'`. There is no corresponding shortcut for `OFS`; if you want to set it from outside the `awk` script, use `-v OFS=':  '` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the use of `-OFS`.

POSIX guidelines for command-line parsing indicate that after a single dash, flags are parsed character by character. Thus, this means `-O`, and `-FS` -- with the `-FS` overriding the `-F ': *'` with a value of just `S`.

If you want to set OFS, doing it in a `BEGIN` block is the Right Thing.